# String formatting by inserting ':'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a string '0000000000000201' in python

```
dpid_string = '0000000000000201'
```

Which is the best way to convert this to the following string

```
00:00:00:00:00:00:02:01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd partition the string into chunks of size 2, and join them with `str.join()`:

```
':'.join([dpid_string[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(dpid_string), 2)])
```

Demo:

```
>>> dpid_string = '0000000000000201'
>>> ':'.join([dpid_string[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(dpid_string), 2)])
'00:00:00:00:00:00:02:01'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
seq = '0000000000000201'
length = 2
":".join([seq[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(seq), length)])
```

Comment: If you need, say for an odd length string, to have the leftmost digit alone (we write 1'000 instead of 100'0 and 9:48 instead of 94:8), do not hesitate to reverse seq and then re-reverse the result.

Answer (score 1):

Although not very simple, you can do

```
dpid_string = '0000000000000201'
''.join([':' + char if not i % 2 else char for i, char in enumerate(dpid_string)])[1:]
```

To break it down from within the list comprehension:

1. `[char for char in dpid_string]` just loops over characters and returns them as a list.
2. We want it to return a string, so we join the full list using `''.join(list)`.
3. Now we want it to react on the location of the character, so we want to assess the index. Therefore we use `i, value in enumerate(list)`
4. If this index is even, add a colon before the char (modulus 2 is False).
5. Now this leaves us with a colon at index 0, we remove it by indexing `[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `re.sub`:

```
import re

dpid_string = '0000000000000201'
subbed = re.sub('(..)(?!$)', r'\1:', dpid_string)
# 00:00:00:00:00:00:02:01
```

Read as take every 2 characters that aren't at the end of the string, and replace it with those two characters followed by `:`.